# can't convert time stamp date to string in swift 4

Tags: swift, date-formatting

I'm trying to convert a timeStamp string date to Date.

The result always returns nil.

```
func getDatefromTimeStamp (str_date : String , strdateFormat: String) -> String { 
    // stringDate '2018-01-01T00:00:00.000+03:00' 
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter() 
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0) as TimeZone! 


    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: str_date) 
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = strdateFormat 
    let datestr = dateFormatter.string(from: date!) 
    return datestr 
}
```

Comment: Please post code and errors as not, not as pictures. Also show the exact string  you are trying to parse.

Comment: func getDatefromTimeStamp (str_date : String , strdateFormat: String) -> String
    {
        //  stringDate '2018-01-01T00:00:00.000+03:00' 
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0) as TimeZone!
        
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: str_date)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = strdateFormat
        let datestr = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
        return datestr
        
    }
@rmaddy

Comment: [Edit] your question. Don't put information in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your primary issue is that the format `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"` does not match a string such as `"2018-01-01T00:00:00.000+03:00"`. That string contains milliseconds but your format doesn't.

Update your format to `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"`.

That will fix the `nil` result.

Then you should clean-up your use of `NSTimeZone`. Just use `TimeZone`.

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
```

But there is no need to set the timezone when parsing this string because the string includes timezone information.

However, you may or may not want a timezone set when converting the resulting `Date` into the new `String`. It depends on what result you want.

Do you want the final string in UTC time (which is what you will get with your current code) or do you want the final string in the user's local time?

If you want the final string in the user's local time, don't set the timezone property at all. It will default to local time.

Answer (score 0):

First of i highly recommend that you use guards instead of forces

Secondly why are you setting the date format twice? the first time is  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" then a few lines later resetting it with the parameter you passed in dateFormatter.dateFormat = strdateFormat. pick one and set it in the beginning - that may be causing your problem

Thirdly if that above is not the problem - make sure that your date is exactly in the necessary format if it is at all wrong it will return nil.  even spaces and colons have to be perfect, i suggest using string builder to make sure they are consistant